# What to do for questions on upgrading from EOL releases

Tags: discussion, end-of-life

So I came across a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499440/do-release-upgrade-could-not-determine-the-upgrade) where the OP was trying to upgrade from an EOL release. Under normal circumstances, any (new) questions about an EOL release should be closed, but what about someone trying to get *off* of an EOL release by upgrading?

There's a page in the Ubuntu wiki about upgrading from EOL releases (although it's slightly out of date), which makes me think that there's at least *some* support for upgrading from an EOL release.

I've marked the question to be closed as a duplicate of a question that answers how to upgrade from an EOL release, but there are two other votes to close the question outright. What's the standard on this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a common dupe:

- [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Closing it is the right thing to do. The answer in the master question adds old-releases.ubuntu.com, which contains the archive of all the old releases, so anyone on an old release has a way to move up to a supported release, so it's all good.

Comment: Closing it as a duplicate, not closing it because it's EOL, right?

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate, that way they are given a link to how to get to a supported version of ubuntu.

Comment: @JorgeCastro there are already [~350 duplicates of that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/linked/91815?lq=1). If they are not finding it, is because they are just not searching.

Comment: It's not their fault we just 404 mirrors without leaving them instructions, it's kind of hard to search for unless you know what to look for.

Comment: So, feature-request in LaunchPad?

Comment: BTW not every release is archived http://askubuntu.com/q/483906/184942