# Close Voters: Questions about upgrading EOL releases aren't off-topic

Tags: discussion, scope

There have been many instances* where I see off-topic close votes on questions that are about upgrading EOL releases to a supported one.

According to [help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic):

> #### Questions that you should avoid:
>
> - Support for versions for Ubuntu releases past their Support or "End of Life" (EOL) — unless the question is asking how to upgrade to a supported release.

If we adhere to the policies and follow the help center, I don't think questions about upgrading an EOL release should be considered as off-topic. It may be a duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/) but not necessarily, for example, [How to upgrade from 18.10 to 19.10, using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1208109/) is a specific question and has an excellent answer.

At the end of the day we're a community and are here to help needy and answer *supported Ubuntu specific* questions.

Suggestions are welcome as comments or answers.

---

***Some Instances I'm aware of:**

- [Problem when i try update linux ubuntu 18.10](https://askubuntu.com/q/1161907/816190) (deleted by Community♦️)
- ["W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package xxxx" while trying to upgrade Xubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1162333)
- [do-release-upgrade not finding next version](https://askubuntu.com/q/1260697/816190) (Current)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Errors while upgrading from a EOL release -- should the question be closed?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14292/errors-while-upgrading-from-a-eol-release-should-the-question-be-closed) or https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11550/what-to-do-for-questions-on-upgrading-from-eol-releases or https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13837/reminder-questions-on-eol-releases-are-not-off-topic-simply-because-theyre-eol I am sure there are more, this comes up quite often.

Comment: @Mark I'm not sure if this question is really a duplicate. I'd leave the fate of this question to the community. But here's my opinion, I think I posted a generalized *appeal*. The first question you linked was specific IMHO. The second one's answer suggested to use a common dupe which I think isn't a very good idea. The third one wasn't about the questions about upgrading.

Comment: The third link is asking that people don't close EOL questions indiscriminately, the same as you ask here, just in a more general way but my point is mostly that this comes up quite a lot.

Comment: You could provide links to previous meta questions in which very, very similar issues have been discussed.

Comment: Here is my POV because I commented on that post: I completely agree that these questions should not be closed, but depending on *how outdated* the EOL release, sometimes it is worth pointing out to OP that it is probably less of a headache to reinstall, instead of seek an answer on how to upgrade an EOL release

Comment: @Nmath Yes that actually makes sense. But still that won't be off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

### Flag things being incorrectly closed.

Let us sort them out. That's the short answer.

The longer extension to that is to [please] just be careful what you're looking at.

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161907/problem-when-i-try-update-linux-ubuntu-18-10 is about `apt-get update` errors. <strike>It is off-topic.</strike> You're right, the actual problem here is [probably] that the PPA just didn't release for 18.10 and 19.04 and an answer for that would have been helpful.
- ["W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package xxxx" while trying to upgrade Xubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162333/w-ignoring-provides-line-with-depcompareop-for-package-xxxx-while-trying-to-u) is about `apt-get dist-upgrade` errors. It is off-topic.
- [do-release-upgrade not finding next version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260697/do-release-upgrade-not-finding-next-version) contains somebody *moaning about* the release age but the close-reason is duplicate. But yes, that's on-topic.

Comment: First one has a comment, "*Yes i did it, and was able to upgraded to 19.04, but the error keeps showing up.*". So, I guess they were already on 19.04 which was supported then. Since installing pending updates is the very first step to upgrade a release, I interpreted second question that way. I may be missing things in the second one. It's unclear if not off-topic. On a lighter note, I'd like to keep this discussion open.

Comment: You're right, the first one is okay. I've edited. But it's not an example of a question about "upgrading EOL releases to a supported one". I have no problem with the idea that *those* sorts of questions are on-topic, just reminding you that not all old-release questions with the words "update" or "upgrade" in them are about upgrading to a later version of Ubuntu.

Comment: I do agree but that question is, I think, about the aftermath of upgrading. Must be a bad example though. And yes I do agree that all old-release questions having update/upgrade aren't about upgrading to a supported release. I admit that I should have provided better examples.